# Getting IndexOutOfBundException Android

Tags: java, android, list, view, indexoutofboundsexception

I am retrieving events from database in a list. I am creating dynamic events. I have set id to the events and retrieving in a list.

I want to get data of the event which will be clicked. I tried to retrieve value but getting out of index exception when I click on any event.

Here is my attempt to get data:

```
public int tag;

private EventTableHelper db;
private EventData mEvent;

  if(editMode)//true
    {
        id = i.getIntExtra("tag", 0);
        List<EventData> eventList = db.getAllEvents(id);
        mEvent = eventList.get(id);
        title.setText(mEvent.getTitle());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(id),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        db.updateEvent(eventData);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Edit mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Getting exception on:  mEvent = eventList.get(id);

EDIT :

Creating event function :

```
 for (EventData eventData : events) {

        String datefrom = eventData.getFromDate();

        if(datefrom != null) {
            String[] times = datefrom.substring(11, 16).split(":");
            minutesFrom = Integer.parseInt(times[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times[1]);
        }
        String dateTo = eventData.getToDate();

        String title = eventData.getTitle();
        String location = eventData.getLocation();


        if(dateTo != null) {

            String[] times1 = dateTo.substring(11, 16).split(":");
            minutesTo = Integer.parseInt(times1[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times1[1]);
        }
        tag ++;
        createEvent(inflater, dayplanView, minutesFrom, minutesTo,title,location);

    }
```

CreateEvent :

```
  private void createEvent(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup dayplanView, int fromMinutes, int toMinutes, String title,String location) {
    final View eventView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_view, dayplanView, false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) eventView.getLayoutParams();

    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) eventView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) eventView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);

    TextView showLocation = (TextView)eventView.findViewById(R.id.Location);
    TextView at = (TextView)eventView.findViewById(R.id.At);


    if (tvTitle.getParent() != null)
       ((ViewGroup) tvTitle.getParent()).removeView(tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText(title);
    if (showLocation.getParent() != null)
       ((ViewGroup) showLocation.getParent()).removeView(showLocation);

    if (at.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) at.getParent()).removeView(at);

    if(location.equals(""))
    {
        showLocation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        at.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    else
    {
        showLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        at.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        showLocation.setText(location);
    }

    int distance = (toMinutes - fromMinutes);

    layoutParams.topMargin = dpToPixels(fromMinutes + 9);
    layoutParams.height = dpToPixels(distance);

    eventView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    dayplanView.addView(eventView);
    container.addView(tvTitle);
    container.addView(showLocation);
    container.addView(at);

    eventView.setTag(tag);

    eventView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
            editMode = true;
            i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);

            v.getTag(tag);
            i.putExtra("tag",tag);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
```

I am setting and passing tag from fragment to activity.

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried printing `id`? What's likely happening is that you are trying to access an element that doesn't exist because the index is too high.

Comment: Better to get record based `Position`  instead of `Id`

Comment: Run your app in debug mode and look for the size of eventList and the value of id. Your eventList could have size of 0 or may be the item you are trying to retrieve from eventList with id as a index, does not exist.

Comment: I tried to debug id. It dose set for each event. Please check edited code.@ Arc676

Comment: How can I get position of dynamic view here in my code? @MD

Comment: I tried to debug this the array size shows 3. mEvent = eventList.get(id-1); by reading one of solution on SO then i get id as 3. For every event i click. @ Vikalp.

Comment: If the size is 3 and the index (id) is also 3 that is your problem. if I get it right. The indexes in the array are from 0 to size -1 so in your case would be 0,1,2 so when you try to get an element at index 3 that's why it's crashing.

Comment: Sorry confused. What should I edit ? @Alex

Comment: Try changing v.getTag(tag);  into  int eventViewTag = (int) v.getTag();  and  i.putExtra("tag",tag); into i.putExtra("tag",eventViewTag);

Comment: Thank you for help solved it with the same..and some more change@innich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

> v.getTag(tag);

into

> int eventViewTag = (int) v.getTag();

and

> i.putExtra("tag",tag);

into

> i.putExtra("tag",eventViewTag);